# how to put both nodes in same cycle?

Tags: php, foreach, nodes, domxpath

This is what I use:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("https://www.gismeteo.ru/city/weekly/4230/");
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$weekday= $xpath->query('//*[@id="weather-weekly"]//div[@class="weekday"]');
$date= $xpath->query('//*[@id="weather-weekly"]//div[@class="s_date"]');

foreach ($weekday as $node4){
foreach ($date as $node3){
echo $node4->nodeValue,$node3->nodeValue,"<br>";}}
```

`$node4->nodeValue` prints out day of the week `sun, mon, tue...` and `$node3->nodeValue` prints out day of the month, how do I make it print everything in the same column like this `sat 23.07, sun 24.08...`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$days = $xpath->query('//*[@id="weather-weekly"]//div[@class="wbshort"]');
foreach ($days as $day) {
   // find weekday and date under day
   $weekday= $xpath->query('.//div[@class="weekday"]', $day);
   $date= $xpath->query('.//div[@class="s_date"]', $day);
   echo $weekday->item(0)->nodeValue . " " . $date->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I have got this error `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to DOMXPath::query() must be an instance of DOMNode`

Comment: Sorry,  it's a typo - i lost `$` before day

Comment: Okay, but how do I make it to print all list? It only prints first item, I have tried to set `foreach ($days as $i => $day)` and items to `item($i)` didn't help.

Comment: @MakeMeWise  I watched the page structure and rewrote the code

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!